# Allocate CFString in subfunction

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to allocate space for CFString in a subfunction. Something like this:

```
void fun(CFStringRef *ref)
{
    ref = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "hi", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}

int main(void)
{
    CFStringRef ref;
    fun(&ref);

    CFShow(ref);

    if(ref) CFRelease(ref);
    return 0;
}
```

It does compile with a warning and doesn't print "hi". What's wrong here?

EDIT:
added CFRelease()

Comment: It's perhaps also worth mentioning that the CFString you create here is leaked. You probably want to add: if (ref) CFRelease(ref); before you return.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. (Although in the actual code I do release). Added it to the example too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CFStringCreateWithCString()` returns a `CFStringRef`, not a `CFStringRef *`. You have to dereference the pointer in the assignment:

```
*ref = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "hi", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Edit: for your next question, please don't just say "it compiles with a warning". Tell us the actual warning message. It makes answering your question so much easier.